# Compute field - insert into m2m relation table

Tags: sql-insert, odoo, odoo-10

In model `project.task` I create many2many field `x_something` linked to another model.

So, in this relation table there is a field `id` from `project.task` and another model.

And in another field of `project.task` I wanna write a function in compute section and in this function I wanna insert a record into this relation table by:

`self.env.cr.execute( "INSERT INTO x_table_rel VALUES (value_a,value_b)" )`

values are inserted but I don't see connection in odoo, it's blank.

What did I miss?

Comment: Why do you want to insert rows like that instead of using Odoo's ORM layer?

Comment: Please check the documentation on https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference − in write(vals) section

Answer (score 0):

Will you please post the code you're trying to work with?

Odoo has a system for creating related tables.

in each class declare

```
    related_class_id= fields.Many2many('related.class','related_table_name', 'current_class_id', 'related_class_id')
```

then in one of the classes set the related_class_id.

This should set the relationship.